# ResizeObserver don't work as expected on Windows

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, resize

I was playing with ResizeObserver (that's supported by google chrome behind experimental web platform flag). I've create codepen demo using jQuery UI resizable. It work fine on chromium linux, but on Windows it stops after a while or execute only once.

My code look like this:

```
$('#node').css({
  width: 140,
  height: 50
}).resizable();

function resizer(node, callback) {
  if (window.ResizeObserver) {
    var resizer = new ResizeObserver(function(entries) {
      callback(entries[0]);
    });
    resizer.observe(node);
    return () => resizer.unobserve(node);
  } else {
    return () => undefined;
  }
}
resizer(document.querySelector('.content'), function(entry) {
  var width = entry.contentRect.width;
  var height = entry.contentRect.height
  console.log(width + 'x' + height);
  // custom event found on
  // https://ebidel.github.io/demos/dom_resize_events.html
  entry.target.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('resize', {
    detail: {width,height}
  }));
});
document.querySelector('.content').addEventListener('resize', (e) => {
  console.log(e.detail);
});
```

I've try to restart the browser, close/open developer tools also download the files to local drive and open using file protocol and got the same results.

the [google chrome example](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/resizeobserver/) works fine,

Here is a [my pen](https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/GOdaym?editors=1010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the observer get Garbage Collected, adding

```
var r;
...
function resizer(node, callback) {
   ...
   var resizer = new ResizeObserver(...);
   r = resizer;
   ...
}
```

solved the issue

Comment: This was a Chrome bug for a few months. This should no longer be necessary. crbug.com/735830